# gulp-watch requires watch task to be a function. But the task is already a function

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

When I try to run my watch task with gulp I get the error:

> Error: watching ./src/sass/**.scss: watch task has to be a function
>   (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)

However, the task is a function:

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/sass/**.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**.js', ['scripts']);
});
```

What could be happening here?

Comment: `['sass']` and `['scripts']` aren't functions but `gulp.series('sass')` is - look up how to migrate from gulp v3 to v4.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seems that you are using gulp 4, but write the syntax gulp 3. so to solve the problem just add gulp.series (nameOfTask)

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
gulp.watch('./src/sass/**.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
gulp.watch('./src/js/**.js', gulp.series('scripts'));
});
```

you can Check out this post https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/